# Microsoft StreamInsight - cloud based?

Tags: streaminsight

I have a very short question:

Is MS StreamInsight cloud based or can it run locally on a machine?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

StreamInsight can run on a local machine or on-prem server. It's not cloud based. Stream Analytics is similar, but it is cloud based.